# How to make WPF UserControl transparent if it is a child window of a GDI+ application?

Tags: wpf, transparency, gdi+

I'm a beginner with desktop development. I added WPF UserControl as a child window of GDI+ native C++ application with HwndSource, but background for my UserControl is not transparent (it is transparent as I use this UserControl in a pure WPF application). It is rendered as non-transparent black regardless if I set it to null or Transparent. Is there any way to make background transparent for my WPF UserControl and what are my options here?

Comment: Please post some code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UsesPerPixelOpacity = true; from HwndSourceParameters have resolved the issue.
Also need to set Window Style flags:

```
    p.WindowStyle = (int)0x94000C00;
    p.ExtendedWindowStyle = 0x00080088;
```